# Angular 9 *ngIf bug

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 9 project. I have a component and it has a boolean property. I use it to display either one icon or another. My code is like this:

Component ts:

```
    @Input() running: Boolean = false;
```

Component html

```
    <i *ngIf="running" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin mr-1"></i>
    <i *ngIf="!running" class="fa fa-trash"></i>
```

I change the running property to true and I can see the spinner appears however the other icon doesn't disappear. I have tried everything I can come up with and nothing works. There seams to be a redraw bug in Angular when redrawing components.

I have tried

```
    <i *ngIf="!!running" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin mr-1"></i> !! Double bang
    <i *ngIf="!running" class="fa fa-trash"></i>
```

I have tried setting the local running property to Boolean instead of boolean. I have renamed the running property (In case of some weird naming conflict) and that doesn't work either. I have tried putting the i tag inside ng-template with the ngIf conditions and that doesn't work either. I have tried using function call instead of field binding in the ngIf like this:

```
    <i *ngIf="isRunning()" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin mr-1"></i>
    <i *ngIf="!isRunning()" class="fa fa-trash"></i>
```

and I created a isRunning function that returns running and that doesnt work either. Is there are redraw bug in Angular causing this error?

Comment: Can you please create and share a stackblitz of your code ?

Comment: can you interpolate the `running` input to make sure it has the correct value at the correct time?

Comment: Please check if the CSS selector `fa-trash` is applied to any other elements in the DOM. If possible, post a screenshot of the generated DOM.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue but I can't reproduce it. For me everything works as expected. Would you mind sharing a stackblitz which shows your described behavior?

Comment: Please also try once: `<i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-spinner fa-spin mr-1': running, 'fa-trash': !running}"></i>`

Comment: What's the code for your parent component? Could it be setting the value of running?

Comment: Try strict equality. `running === true` and `running === false`.

Comment: As asked by @mbdavis, please show us how you bind the `running` property in the parent component.

Comment: 1. Strict equality didn't work.
2. I interpolated the running flag and it is set properly. I can see the property change on the screen
3. <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-spinner fa-spin mr-1': running, 'fa-trash': !running}"></i> didnt work either
4. I have removed the @input() from the running flag so that it is only set in the component

None of these work. I have created a stackblitz example and it does work so I have no iadea what I am doing any different. I will continue looking for an answer.

https://angular-ivy-fncjs9.stackblitz.io

Comment: I truly beleive there is a bug in Angular. Everytime I press the button an extra icon appears in the button. No error in my developer console.I have also tried Firefox and it too has the same behaviour. Seams like Angular is not updating the component properly.

Comment: @MartijnHiemstra, I'm prety sure the error is not a bug. Check, when you change the value of the variable, you use a boolean value, it's not the same running="false" that running=false. You can check also if you has another variable "running". I'll feel crazy one time that I use a template reference variable (in the html the `#variable` with the same name than a variable in .ts